# Convert text value in SQL from ISO-8859-1

Tags: sql

I have some data in SQL that is falsely formatted:

"Daniel Bødtker" is displayed in ISO 8859-1 format: "=?iso-8859-1?Q?Daniel_B=F8dtker?="

Does anyone have a fix function ready to share?

Thanks!

Daniel

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: This needs *waaaayyyy* more context. Where is the data coming from? What database are you using? What collation/character set do your tables have? The database is unlikely to do this to your string - there is probably something else at play...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not ISO8859-1 format. That's RFC 2047 format, used for transmitting international characters in email headers, which technically only support 7-bit ASCII.

These values have almost certainly been extracted from email headers by a process which does not understand RFC2047.

Format is:

```
"=?" + character set name + "?" + encoding identifier + "?" + encoded data + "?="
```

The encoding identifier is either `Q` or `B`. `Q` means "Quoted-Printable" and `B` means "Base64".

Note that an email header can have multiple such sequences.

Therefore your solution needs to search for these sequences, and handle them on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: Thank you. It appeared that Outlook < 2013 mis-understood the data. Outlook was being used to convert EML files to MSG, and indeed caused the email header to be converted without understanding RFC2047.